# Wrong reference to custom AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, avplayer

I have a `UICollectionView` with multiple cells (`FeedCell`). Those cells can also contain a `UICollectionView` which can also have multiple cells, up to five (`MediaSliderCell`). Basically, the set up is the same as Instagram: you have a post, and one post can have multiple images or videos.

The problem I am now facing is, sometimes the wrong video is shown in the wrong cell. I use an imageView to show a placeholder when the video is not played yet, this placeholder is hidden when the video starts playing (play button is tapped).

I figured everything goes well when the videos are not playing, but the problem arises when I do play videos. The cells get switched up, meaning the video of `MediaSliderCell indexPath.item` 5 is shown in `MediaSLiderCell indexPath.item` 2, for example.

At first, I thought the problem was in the cells, which don't get reused well, but this would also mean the photos could get switched up, which never happens. So I feel the problem is in my AVPlayer, which then uses the wrong reference or wrong URL. Let me demonstrate my code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "mediaSliderCell", for: indexPath) as! MediaSliderCell
    cell.layer.shouldRasterize = true
    cell.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
        if(HomeControllerID.userFeed.userFeed[feedCellID!].userMedia!.count > 0) {
            if(HomeControllerID.userFeed.userFeed[feedCellID!].userMedia![indexPath.item].mediaType == .photo) {
                    let mediaURL = URL(string: "https://myfileserver.com/media/\(HomeControllerID.userFeed.userFeed[feedCellID!].feedID!)/\(HomeControllerID.userFeed.userFeed[feedCellID!].userMedia![indexPath.item].mediaURL)")
                    cell.photoView.kf.setImage(with: mediaURL, options: [.targetCache(mediaCache)])
                    cell.photoView.isHidden = false
                    cell.videoView.isHidden = true
            } else if(HomeControllerID.userFeed.userFeed[feedCellID!].userMedia![indexPath.item].mediaType == .video) {
                let mediaThumbURL = URL(string: "https://myfileserver.com/media/\(HomeControllerID.userFeed.userFeed[feedCellID!].feedID!)/\(HomeControllerID.userFeed.userFeed[feedCellID!].userMedia![indexPath.item].mediaThumbURL!)")
                let mediaURL = URL(string: "https://myfileserver.com/media/\(HomeControllerID.userFeed.userFeed[feedCellID!].feedID!)/\(HomeControllerID.userFeed.userFeed[feedCellID!].userMedia![indexPath.item].mediaURL)")!
                cell.videoView.placeholderView.kf.setImage(with: mediaThumbURL, options: [.targetCache(mediaCache)])
                cell.videoView.mediaURL = mediaURL
                cell.photoView.isHidden = true
                cell.videoView.isHidden = false
            }
    }
    return cell
}
```

`MediaSLiderCell` is some pretty basic `UICollectionViewCell` stuff:

```
class MediaSliderCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        photoView.isHidden = false
        videoView.isHidden = true
        videoView.mediaURL = nil
        videoView.placeholderView.kf.cancelDownloadTask()
        videoView.placeholderView.image = UIImage()
        photoView.image = UIImage()
    }

    var photoView: UIImageView = {
        let photoView = UIImageView()
        photoView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        photoView.backgroundColor = .black
        photoView.isHidden = true
        return photoView
    }()

    var videoView: VideoView = {
        let videoView = VideoView()
        videoView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        videoView.backgroundColor = .black
        return videoView
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
    }

    func setupViews() {
        addSubview(photoView)
        addSubview(videoView)
        photoView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        photoView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        photoView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        photoView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        videoView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        videoView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        videoView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        videoView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

I think all of the above is fine. But then, for the VideoView, I use a custom `UIView` in which I set up a placeholder (`UIImageView`). It's a lot of code below, but most if it is controls and user interface stuff. What's important to know is, I use two libraries: [Cache](https://github.com/hyperoslo/Cache) and [CachingPlayerItem](https://github.com/neekeetab/CachingPlayerItem). This is to avoid downloading the same video over and over again, so when the video is not found in cache, I download the item, and when the video is downloaded, I save it in cache to reuse later. All makes sense I guess. I feel the problem lies somewhere in there, or in the AVPlayer itself. Take a look at the code:

```
class VideoView: UIView, CachingPlayerItemDelegate {
    var playerItem: CachingPlayerItem?
    func playerItem(_ playerItem: CachingPlayerItem, didFinishDownloadingData data: Data) {
        // A track is downloaded. Saving it to the cache asynchronously.
        print("Saving video to cache on device")
        storage?.async.setObject(data, forKey: mediaURL.absoluteString, completion: { _ in} )
    }
    var playerLooper: NSObject?
    var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer!
    var queuePlayer: AVQueuePlayer?
    var mediaURL: URL!
    var placeholderView: UIImageView = {
        let placeholderView = UIImageView()
        placeholderView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        placeholderView.backgroundColor = .black
        return placeholderView
    }()

    var playerView: UIView = {
        let playerView = UIView()
        playerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        playerView.backgroundColor = .clear
        playerView.isHidden = true
        return playerView
    }()

    var playButton: UIImageView = {
        let playButton = UIImageView()
        playButton.image = UIImage(named: "playButton")
        playButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        playButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        playButton.backgroundColor = .clear
        return playButton
    }()

    var pauseButton: UIImageView = {
        let pauseButton = UIImageView()
        pauseButton.image = UIImage(named: "pauseButton")
        pauseButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        pauseButton.backgroundColor = .clear
        pauseButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        pauseButton.alpha = 0
        return pauseButton
    }()

    var volumeOnButton: UIImageView = {
        let volumeOnButton = UIImageView()
        volumeOnButton.image = UIImage(named: "volumeOn")
        volumeOnButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        volumeOnButton.backgroundColor = .clear
        volumeOnButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        volumeOnButton.alpha = 0
        return volumeOnButton
    }()

    var volumeOffButton: UIImageView = {
        let volumeOffButton = UIImageView()
        volumeOffButton.image = UIImage(named: "volumeOff")
        volumeOffButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        volumeOffButton.backgroundColor = .clear
        volumeOffButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        volumeOffButton.alpha = 0
        return volumeOffButton
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.setupViews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.setupViews()
    }

    func setupViews() {
        addSubview(placeholderView)
        placeholderView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        placeholderView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        placeholderView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        placeholderView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        addSubview(playerView)
        playerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        playerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        playerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        playerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        let tapView = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(showControls))
        playerView.addGestureRecognizer(tapView)
        addSubview(playButton)
        playButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        playButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        playButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: profilePicWidth * 2).isActive = true
        playButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: profilePicWidth * 2).isActive = true
        let tapPlayButton = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(playVideo))
        playButton.addGestureRecognizer(tapPlayButton)
        addSubview(pauseButton)
        pauseButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        pauseButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        pauseButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: profilePicWidth * 2).isActive = true
        pauseButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: profilePicWidth * 2).isActive = true
        let tapPauseButton = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(pauseVideo))
        pauseButton.addGestureRecognizer(tapPauseButton)
        addSubview(volumeOnButton)
        volumeOnButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -(normalSpacing + 2)).isActive = true
        volumeOnButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: normalSpacing + 2).isActive = true
        volumeOnButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32).isActive = true
        volumeOnButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32).isActive = true
        let tapVolumeOnButton = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(volumeAction))
        volumeOnButton.addGestureRecognizer(tapVolumeOnButton)
        addSubview(volumeOffButton)
        volumeOffButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -(normalSpacing + 2)).isActive = true
        volumeOffButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: normalSpacing + 2).isActive = true
        volumeOffButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32).isActive = true
        volumeOffButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32).isActive = true
        let tapVolumeOffButton = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(volumeAction))
        volumeOffButton.addGestureRecognizer(tapVolumeOffButton)
    }

    @objc func volumeAction() {
        buttonTimer?.invalidate()
        volumeTimer?.invalidate()
        if UserDefaults.exists(key: "volumeOn") {
            if(UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "volumeOn") == false) {
                self.queuePlayer?.isMuted = false
                UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "volumeOn")
                self.volumeOnButton.alpha = 1
                self.volumeOffButton.alpha = 0
            } else {
                self.queuePlayer?.isMuted = true
                UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "volumeOn")
                self.volumeOnButton.alpha = 0
                self.volumeOffButton.alpha = 1
            }
        } else {
            self.queuePlayer?.isMuted = false
            UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "volumeOn")
            self.volumeOnButton.alpha = 1
            self.volumeOffButton.alpha = 0
        }
        volumeTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2.5, target: self, selector: #selector(fadeVolumeButton), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        buttonTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2.5, target: self, selector: #selector(fadePauseButton), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }

    @objc func checkVolume() {
        if UserDefaults.exists(key: "volumeOn") {
            if(UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "volumeOn") == false) {
                self.queuePlayer?.isMuted = true
            } else {
                self.queuePlayer?.isMuted = false
            }
        } else {
            self.queuePlayer?.isMuted = true
        }
    }

    @objc func showControls() {
        buttonTimer?.invalidate()
        volumeTimer?.invalidate()
        if(self.volumeOnButton.alpha > 0 || self.volumeOffButton.alpha > 0) {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
                self.volumeOnButton.alpha = 0
                self.volumeOffButton.alpha = 0
            }
        } else {
            if UserDefaults.exists(key: "volumeOn") {
                if(UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "volumeOn") == false) {
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
                        self.volumeOffButton.alpha = 1
                        self.volumeOnButton.alpha = 0
                    }
                } else {
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
                        self.volumeOffButton.alpha = 0
                        self.volumeOnButton.alpha = 1
                    }
                }
            } else {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
                    self.volumeOffButton.alpha = 1
                    self.volumeOnButton.alpha = 0
                }
            }
            volumeTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2.5, target: self, selector: #selector(fadeVolumeButton), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        }

        if(self.queuePlayer?.timeControlStatus == .playing) {
            if(self.pauseButton.alpha > 0) {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) { self.pauseButton.alpha = 0 }
            } else {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) { self.pauseButton.alpha = 1 }
                buttonTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2.5, target: self, selector: #selector(fadePauseButton), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
            }
        } else if(self.queuePlayer?.timeControlStatus == .paused) {
            if(self.playButton.alpha > 0) {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) { self.pauseButton.alpha = 0 }
            } else {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) { self.playButton.alpha = 1 }
            }
        }
    }

    lazy var storage: Cache.Storage? = {
        return try? Storage(diskConfig: diskConfig, memoryConfig: memoryConfig, transformer: TransformerFactory.forData())
    }()

    func loadVideo() {
        // Trying to retrieve a track from cache asynchronously.
        storage?.async.entry(forKey: mediaURL.absoluteString, completion: { result in
            switch result {
            case .error:
                // The track is not cached.
                print("Downloading from network")
                self.playerItem = CachingPlayerItem(url: self.mediaURL)
            case .value(let entry):
                // The track is cached.
                print("Downloading from cached library on device")
                self.playerItem = CachingPlayerItem(data: entry.object, mimeType: "video/mp4", fileExtension: "mp4")
            }
            self.playerItem?.delegate = self
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let playerItem = self.playerItem {
                    self.queuePlayer = AVQueuePlayer(items: [playerItem])
                    self.queuePlayer?.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = false
                    self.playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.queuePlayer)
                    self.playerLooper = AVPlayerLooper(player: self.queuePlayer!, templateItem: playerItem)
                    self.playerView.layer.addSublayer(self.playerLayer!)
                    self.playerLayer?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 1.25)
                    self.checkVolume()
                    do {
                       try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback)
                    } catch(let error) {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                    self.queuePlayer?.play()
                    self.queuePlayer?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "timeControlStatus", options: .initial, context:nil)
                }
            }
        })
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if(keyPath == "timeControlStatus") {
            if(self.playerView.isHidden && self.queuePlayer?.timeControlStatus == .playing) {
                self.playerView.isHidden = false
            }
        }
    }

    var buttonTimer: Timer?
    var volumeTimer: Timer?

    @objc func playVideo() {
        buttonTimer?.invalidate()
        volumeTimer?.invalidate()
        if(self.queuePlayer?.currentItem == nil) {
            self.loadVideo()
        }
        if(self.queuePlayer?.timeControlStatus == .paused) {
            do {
               try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback)
            } catch(let error) {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            self.queuePlayer?.play()
        }
        self.playButton.alpha = 0
        buttonTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.5, target: self, selector: #selector(fadePauseButton), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        volumeTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.5, target: self, selector: #selector(fadeVolumeButton), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }

    @objc func pauseVideo() {
        buttonTimer?.invalidate()
        self.queuePlayer?.pause()
        self.playButton.alpha = 1
        self.pauseButton.alpha = 0
        self.volumeOnButton.alpha = 0
        self.volumeOffButton.alpha = 0
    }

    @objc func fadePauseButton() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8) {
            self.pauseButton.alpha = 0
        }
    }

    @objc func fadeVolumeButton() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8) {
            self.volumeOnButton.alpha = 0
            self.volumeOffButton.alpha = 0
        }
    }
}
```

In my opinion, the problem should be somewhere above in `loadVideo()`. However, I provide all my code of the custom `UIView` VideoView to avoid any mistakes or other important parts. Anybody who can help me? Would help me out a big deal, because I've been looking into this for weeks now. I have tried every suggestion for dequeuing, I have tried everything I could for reusing cells, ... and it all didn't work. So I guess the solution should be found in the `AVPlayer`, the `Cache` library or the `CachingPlayerItem` library. Would appreciate any help or suggestions. Thank you in advance.

*For the record, something I forgot but should be clear from the code: the AVPlayer is not shown and thus `loadVideo()` is not called initially. Only when the user taps the play button (`playVideo()`). Everything goes well if I don't play video too. Photos are shown correctly, the placeholders are shown correctly, but the videos get mixed up **after** I start playing one or more videos (tap the play button, which calls `playVideo()`, which calls `loadVideo()`).*

**EDIT: Ok so I figured something out. It seems like the video itself is not changed when the cell gets reused. What I mean is, in loadVideo(), the AVQueuePlayer() gets set, and this is what changes the video shown and played afterwards. I feel like I need to set this block:**

```
    // Trying to retrieve a track from cache asynchronously.
    storage?.async.entry(forKey: mediaURL.absoluteString, completion: { result in

        switch result {
        case .error:
            // The track is not cached.
            print("Downloading from network")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.playerItem = CachingPlayerItem(url: self.mediaURL)
            }
        case .value(let entry):
            // The track is cached.
            print("Downloading from cached library on device")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.playerItem = CachingPlayerItem(data: entry.object, mimeType: "video/mp4", fileExtension: "mp4")
            }
        }

        self.playerItem?.delegate = self

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            if let playerItem = self.playerItem {
                self.queuePlayer = AVQueuePlayer(items: [playerItem])
                self.queuePlayer?.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = false
                self.playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.queuePlayer)
                self.playerLooper = AVPlayerLooper(player: self.queuePlayer!, templateItem: playerItem)
                self.playerView.layer.addSublayer(self.playerLayer!)
                self.playerLayer?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 1.25)
                self.checkVolume()
                do {
                   try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback)
                } catch(let error) {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
                self.queuePlayer?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "timeControlStatus", options: .initial, context:nil)

            }

        }

    })
```

**somewhere else, before the video gets played at all. Because this only gets called when the play button is tapped, but then the wrong video is shown. Have tried calling loadVideo() directly in the cell, but doesn't seem to fix the problem. I feel like I am getting closer tho. Any thoughts?**

Answer (score 0):

Don't store `AVQueuePlayer` inside tableView cells. Remember that you have upper limit on the amount of AVPlayer instances you can keep.

Move players it-selfs, their configurations, starting, pausing, whatever else action you have into `UIViewController` what store your `UITableView`.

When User will press play on `UITableViewCell`, you will tell the `UIViewController` thru `delegate` to start playing and `UIViewController` will do something like that:

1. Cancel previous playing
2. Populate `AVQueuePlayer` with player items
3. Insert `AVQueuePlayer` into `UITableViewCell`
4. Start playing

Don't forget to remove `AVQueuePlayer` from `UITableViewCell` when you reuse cell

Comment: Will change my code this weekend. Two questions: 1. Will this fix the mix up of the videos? It happens also when there is just one feed item being dequeued, so only one AVQueuePlayer. 2. What will happen when two feed items, both with AVQueuePlayer in them, are visible? Will they both show?

Comment: Would it be an idea to use AVPlayer? Could I initiate these in the cells? I only use AVQueuePlayer to automatically replay the video.